# sudo npm install command throw errors

Tags: macos, permissions, sudo, node.js, npm

sudo npm install always throws bunch or errors.

- I have done it with or without sudo,
- I tried it globally and locally,
- I did a clean uninstall and install both for the current version(11.13.0) and LTS(10.15.3),
- I tried after cleaning cash,
- I tried putting --unsafe-perm,
- I tried giving permission to all enclosed items and recursively,
- I tried on Sierra instead of Mojave.

I can't remember what more I have tried, but I did pretty much everything I could find in online.

```
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/Users/juneau/Documents/learning/vue/test/node_modules/fsevents/build'
gyp ERR! System Darwin 18.5.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/Users/juneau/Documents/learning/vue/test/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v64-darwin-x64/fse.node" "--module_name=fse" "--module_path=/Users/juneau/Documents/learning/vue/test/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v64-darwin-x64" "--napi_version=3" "--node_abi_napi=napi"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/juneau/Documents/learning/vue/test/node_modules/fsevents
gyp ERR! node -v v10.15.3
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/Users/juneau/Documents/learning/vue/test/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v64-darwin-x64/fse.node --module_name=fse --module_path=/Users/juneau/Documents/learning/vue/test/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v64-darwin-x64 --napi_version=3 --node_abi_napi=napi' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/juneau/Documents/learning/vue/test/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:189:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:970:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Darwin 18.5.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/Users/juneau/Documents/learning/vue/test/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /Users/juneau/Documents/learning/vue/test/node_modules/fsevents
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v10.15.3
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.10.3
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok 
Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/Users/juneau/Documents/learning/vue/test/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v64-darwin-x64/fse.node --module_name=fse --module_path=/Users/juneau/Documents/learning/vue/test/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v64-darwin-x64 --napi_version=3 --node_abi_napi=napi' (1)
```

I really want to install it at least without high vulnerabilities error.

Comment: @Underverse MacOS Mojave, yes I have tried that as well. I also tried with Sierra but that wasn't good either.

Comment: [Login and execute the install as root](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204012)?

Comment: @Underverse I have just tried after clear the cash, but it was no good either. absolutely no idea what is going on.